# Explode Textarea and Pass IN Select Statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a text area called mycode which receives a list of codes:

```
1234
3456
7654
3456
```

etc...

My php `process.php` script accepts codes:

```
  $codes = $_POST['mycode'];
```

I then attempt to explode the $code into a variable called `$arr`:

```
  $arr = explode("\n", $codes);
```

Next I then try to pass in the `$arr` array into my MySQL SELECT statement:

```
  $sql = "SELECT code, name, FROM rawcodes where code IN ($arr)";
  $rs=$conn->query($sql);
```

I get data returned from the database, BUT its a record that has no code but has a name, therefore its clear that an empty array is getting created therefore passed to the mysql statement.

I have also tried:

```
  $arr = explode(",", $codes);
```

Which also returns an error.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried:

```
implode('","',$arr)
```

So I need the data to actually exist in the array?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: SQL `IN` takes CSV. `explode` on `\n`, `implode` on `,`?

Comment: I gave a longer answer below -- the challenge I see is not just fixing the errors but using a parameter-binding model so that you can prevent injections. You are taking data from $_POST and making SQL out of it, so it's important to use good practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try using this

```
$in = "'".implode("','", array_filter(explode(" ", $codes))) . "'";
$sql = "SELECT code, name FROM rawcodes where code IN ($in)";
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  I've tried your suggestion but my error_log gives me a parse error for the line: $in = "'" . implode(",'", array_filter(explode(" ", $codes))) . "'";

Comment: Yes, I got that & updated. It was just a typing mistake. Can try now.

Comment: [error] [client ::1] PHP Parse error:  parse error in /myproject/process.php on line 21, referer: http://localhost/~myname/myproject/index.html  Line 21 being ....$in = "'" . implode(",'", array etc

Comment: Did you try what I updated? or please show the error. I can't see your provided URL.

Comment: Yes I tried what you updated, but still getting parse error.  Would it make any difference if the codes were not totally numeric, for example GR1235 HR3456 LD5678 ?

Comment: Your SQL string contains an extra comma after name, remove it as I updated & try.

Answer (score 1):

You have an unwanted `,` after `name` in sql

```
$sql = "SELECT code, name, FROM rawcodes where code IN ($arr)";
```

To be

```
$sql = "SELECT code, name FROM rawcodes where code IN ($arr)";
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$_POST['mycode']` is indeed a string like `1234 3456 7654 3456` with space separators, then explode on " ". You changed the post to newlines, so I changed accordingly.

Furthermore, I recommend jumping through some extra hoops to bind each part as a parameter to prevent injection attacks. (Actually, you should validate each part to make sure it contains only digits!!)

The tricky part is that mysqli does not let you bind an array of parameters to a set of markers. This is much easier with PDO where you can have 'named labels' like ':param' in the SQL. With mysqli you have to use call_user_func_array to get the variable number of arguments.

```
// removed extra comma after 'name'
$values = explode("\n", $_POST['mycode']);
$placeholders = "";
$bindTypes = str_repeat("s", count($values));
$params = array(&$bindTypes);
for($i = 0, $len = count($values), $i < $len, $i++) {
    // validate $values[$i] here! 
    if(strlen($placeholders)) $placeholders .= ", ";
    $placeholders .= "p".$i;
    $params[] = &$values[$i];
}

$sql = "SELECT code, name FROM rawcodes where code IN ($placeholders)";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
// make params array act like a comma-separated argument list
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bindparams'), $params);
$rs=$statement->execute();
// check return code, process results here
```

Comment: Great advice RobP.  I will review what I have done and try to implement your all_user_func_array suggestion or re-design the solution using PDO.  Much appreciated.